# How to create a table, insert and get records on it via plugin?

Tags: pyrocms

Ok, I wanted to create a plugin to show feeds on home page. I decided to use plugin for that because if I use module, It will not be a homepage rather than different page like /feeds.

Here's the current code I'm at, its not much but please help.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Send URL Plugin
 *
 * Quick plugin to demonstrate how things work
 *
 * @author  PyroCMS Dev Team
 * @package PyroCMS\Addon\Plugins
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2009 - 2010, PyroCMS
 */
class Plugin_Feeds extends Plugin
{

    public $version = '1.0.0';

    public $name = array(
        'en'    => 'Feeds'
    );

    public $description = array(
        'en'    => 'Loads feeds.'
    );

    public function _self_doc()
    {
        $info = array(
            'Load' => array(
                'description' => array('en' => 'Load feeds.'),
                'single' => true,
                'double' => false,
            )
        );
        return $info;
    }

    public function Load()
    {
            $feeds =   '<div class="feeds">
                            <div class="clearfix user-info">
                                {{ theme:image file="profile-default.jpg" class="user-thumb" width="50px" height="50px" }}
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Waldo</a></li>
                                    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;13 mins ago</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="feed-content">
                                <p>Sample Post</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>'
                    ;
            return $feeds;
    }
}
?>
```

Basically I wanted to get the records via query in a custom table and construct its html on loop and all goes to $feeds variable that would return the result data after I put {{ feeds:Load }} in home. I asked how to create a custom table and set data to it so I could create one mock-up data I could use.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you that you create a model to do the database interactions ( create table, insert and update).
You can the load the model by creating a default constructor.

```
class Plugin_Feeds extends Plugin
//default constructor
 public function __construct() {
    $this->ci = & get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->model('your_model');
}
// other methods for the plugin
}
```

I hope this one will work for you.